# Turn dictionary into csv

Tags: javascript

```
var dict = {
  'Type1':'.typ1',
  'Type2':'.typ2',
  'Type3':'.typ3'
}
```

Any chance there's a concise one-liner to produce CSV like following:

```
".typ1,.typ2,.typ3"
```

Comment: Sure: `Object.keys(dict).map(function(k){return dict[k];}).join(',');`. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Object.keys(dict).map(function(k){
    return dict[k];
}).join(',');
```

Comment: Have escape secuence problems.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery solution :

```
var str = $.map(dict, function(x){return x}).join();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mh9wu3ps/)**